# Node typescript genrics for json response

Tags: node.js, typescript

Sorry it's my first time with node and ts
so I'm a little confused

```
export const successResponseWithData = <T extends unknown>(res, data) => {
  return res.status(200).json(data) as T;
};
```

Usage

```
successResponseWithData<AuthToken>(res, token);
```

Is it the right way?

Answer (score 1):

To use typescript in express it provides many helper methods like RequestHandler below
As per my understanding if you are trying to ensure that `successResponseWithData` should always be of a specific type and the response you sent back is of same type then something like this can be done:

```
export const interface AuthToken {
    item1: <type1>
 };
import {RequestHandler} from 'express';

export const apiEndPoint: RequestHandler = (req, res) => {
 const resp: AuthToken = successResponseWithData();
  return res.status(200).json(resp);
};

successResponseWithData: AuthToken = _ => {
  // calculate token here
  return token;
};
```